# How to combine these 2 SQL query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

1st Query:

```
Select O.TrainDate, O.RailHead, O.Position as Pos, 
    O.Iso, C.CustomerName + ' (' + O.Customer + ')' as Customer, 
    P.ProductName + ' ('+O.Product +')' as Product, 
    O.Target, O.Docket, o.Gross, o.Tare ,o.Net, o.ConNote, o.Description 
from IsoOrders O, Customer C, Product P
where o.Customer = c.Customer 
    and p.Product = o.Product
    and o.Traindate >= '12-14-2016'
    and o.Iso = '040'
```

2nd Query:

```
select top 1 isodeldocket, product from trans where container = '040' 
order by despatchdatetime desc
```

The last query's result was to be added as **the last 2 columns of the 1st query**.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solving the problem in your query

You can do it like this:

```
select 
  O.TrainDate, O.RailHead, O.Position as Pos, O.Iso, 
  C.CustomerName + ' (' + O.Customer + ')' as Customer, 
  P.ProductName + ' ('+ O.Product +')' as Product, 
  O.Target, O.Docket, O.Gross, O.Tare, O.Net, O.ConNote, O.Description, 
  -- Added these columns
  T.isodeldocket, 
  T.product
from 
  IsoOrders O, 
  Customer C, 
  Product P, 
  -- Added this derived table
  (select top 1 isodeldocket, product 
   from trans 
   where container = '040' 
   order by despatchdatetime desc) T
where O.Customer = C.Customer and P.Product = O.Product
and O.Traindate >= '12-14-2016'
and O.Iso = '040'
```

#### Improving the query by using ANSI JOIN syntax

While you're refactoring this query, why not move to ANSI JOIN, which greatly simplifies readability and clearly shows the intent / difference between `(INNER) JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select 
  O.TrainDate, O.RailHead, O.Position as Pos, O.Iso, 
  C.CustomerName + ' (' + O.Customer + ')' as Customer, 
  P.ProductName + ' ('+ O.Product +')' as Product, 
  O.Target, O.Docket, O.Gross, O.Tare, O.Net, O.ConNote, O.Description, 
  T.isodeldocket, 
  T.product
from IsoOrders O
join Customer C on O.Customer = C.Customer 
join Product P on P.Product = O.Product
-- CROSS JOIN more explicitly reveals your intention than a comma-separated table list
cross join (
  select top 1 isodeldocket, product 
  from trans 
  where container = '040' 
  order by despatchdatetime desc
) T
where O.Traindate >= '12-14-2016'
and O.Iso = '040'
```

#### Correlating the "outer" `O.Iso` with the "inner" `trans.container` value

From your comments, I take that you want to take this one step further and avoid duplicating the `'040'` "parameter". This can be done in SQL Server using `APPLY`:

```
select 
  O.TrainDate, O.RailHead, O.Position as Pos, O.Iso, 
  C.CustomerName + ' (' + O.Customer + ')' as Customer, 
  P.ProductName + ' ('+ O.Product +')' as Product, 
  O.Target, O.Docket, O.Gross, O.Tare, O.Net, O.ConNote, O.Description, 
  T.isodeldocket, 
  T.product
from IsoOrders O
join Customer C on O.Customer = C.Customer 
join Product P on P.Product = O.Product
-- Use CROSS APPLY rather than CROSS JOIN
cross apply (
  select top 1 isodeldocket, product 
  from trans 
  where container = O.Iso -- Now, you can access "outer" columns
  order by despatchdatetime desc
) T
where O.Traindate >= '12-14-2016'
and O.Iso = '040'
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your answer.. how do I pass the O.Iso to the cross join query?

Comment: @TrangLe: You mean, you want to correlate `O.Iso = trans.container` to avoid repetition? (given that they're both `'040'` in your query)

Comment: @TrangLe: There... I've updated my answer with a new version that uses `CROSS APPLY`, in case that's what you've meant...

Comment: Thank you Lukas, Its the first time I have heard of Cross Apply!

Comment: @TrangLe: it will be a beautiful long-term relationship! 